# How to prevent Visual Studio Code from launching a PDF viewer when i want to edit the PDF code?

Tags: pdf, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get Visual Studio Code show the actual code of a PDF rather than opening a PDF viewer?

When I open a PDF file in Visual Studio Code (macOS), it launches some PDF viewer with the WYSIWYG version of the file, and I find no menu whatsoever to show me the actual PDF code.

You know, PDF code like,

```
7 0 obj
<</ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/Height 152/Filter/DCTDecode/Type/XObject/Width 304/BitsPerComponent 8/Length 24109>>stream
```

I may have installed an extension that does this WYSIWYG trick, but I don't even see displayed the name of any active extension nor a menu to turn it off or switch to the code.

Is that the default behavior?  If not, how can I identify what causes this behavior, and how to control it?

Comment: Please take [the tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read [how to write a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).  Then edit your question.  Perhaps something specific like "Why does vscode on my mac launch a PDF viewer rather than allowing me to edit the raw text?".

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me :)
Your comment suggests the behavior i describe is not the default behavior, so my problem looks very specific. Is that what you're saying?
I'm afraid asking something about "my mac" is not going to the right direction in terms of a good question. I've tried to restate it though.

Comment: @ChristophePriieur the default for vs code is to warn about pdfs looking like binary files, then open in the text editor. Many extensions will open a PDF viewer/previewer instead. Try searching for 'file associations` in settings, or continue with disabling extensions

Comment: aaah, got it.  It's Latex Workshop (Preferences > Extensions > Show running extensions)